# What sql technique should I use?

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets, mysql-workbench, inventory-management

I'm trying to create a simple inventory management system using java servlet, jsp and mysql. I want to create a table for the brands that are available. My table would have the brand id, brand name, the no. of products available under each brand, and a column called "status" of type boolean which will show if products are available or not. So if the number of products reaches 0, I want the status column to show false, and if it was more than 0, I want it to show true. How do I write this sql logic? I know about basic querying, but what kind of technique can I use to show this, so that the status column would automatically be updated? Any help would be much, much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generated column for status as below:

Create table statements:

```
 create table brands (brand_id int, brand_name varchar(100),no_of_products int, 
 status boolean GENERATED ALWAYS AS (case when no_of_products=0 then false else true end));
```

****if no_of_products is 0 then status column will be 0 otherwise it will be 1**

Insert statements:

```
 insert into brands(brand_id,brand_name,no_of_products) values(1,'hp',0);
 insert into brands(brand_id,brand_name,no_of_products) values(2,'del',5);
```

Select query:

```
 select * from brands
```

Output:

| brand_id | brand_name | no_of_products | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hp | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | del | 5 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f55aa66fe25ae345b7e64a5a5d706afc)*